# функция setDate для дня недели

Tags: php

Добрый день. Мне необходимо получить дату следующей субботы. Пытался Таким образом, но не работает.

```
 $send_day = new DateTime();     
    $send_day -> format('Y-m-N');
    $send_day->setDate(2017,$s11,Saturday);
```

Подскажите, как правильно написать функцию. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
$send_day = new DateTime(); 
$b = date("s"); 
$send_day->modify("+".($b == 0 ? 1:6 - $b)." day")->format('Y-m-N');
```